# File system alternatives for image upload/display

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, hibernate

I got a web application with a Java backend and React frontend. It allows users to upload and display pictures like in an album setting.

The application fetches data from a MS SQL server containing data about an image and then displays it in react.

The database contains a table with information about the image (filename, extension etc.) but not a BLOB.

I am currently displaying the image in react by creating an url from my local machine.

My question is now, what file system alternatives is there when i want to stop storing the images locally on my windows machine. Is it possible to use Google Drive API or something similar? What about SFTP? Would appreciate free solutions to begin with.

Comment: Why not expand the database table and include the blob?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I thought it would cause slow fetching/loading compared to a file system.

Comment: Depends on the connection you have. But everything will be throttled by that connection. If you use Google Drive, its throttled by connection. If you use Amazon S3, its throttled by connection. Sftp as well. So why waste money if you can have it for free?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Amazon S3 to store your images. store information about the image like file name, bucket name ,... etc in your database and store the image itself in Amazon S3.

Answer (score 0):

There are also other alternatives to Amazon S3 if you want, like MinIO, which is open source and S3 compatible.